# Delphi RichEdit - add multiple CFE_LINK effect via CHARFORMAT2

Tags: delphi

I have made a code, that inserts **CFE_LINK** into *RichEdit* text, but it works only for last inserted text. All previous insertions of Links are Undone.

I want to insert multiple Link-texts, but I cant figure out how to do that.

Here is a working code (with no errors):

```
unit uRichEditExtended;

interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, RichEdit, WinApi.ShellApi, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TZ_RichEditClickEvent = reference to procedure(const ALinkText: string);

  TZ_RichEditLink = class
    IsDefaultEvent: boolean;
    Text: string;
    OnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent;
  end;

  TZ_RichEditLinks = TList<TZ_RichEditLink>;

  TRichEditExtended = class
  protected
    class var FInstance: TRichEditExtended;
  private
    FPrevRichEditWndProc: TWndMethod;
    FRichEdit: TRichEdit;
    FRichEditLinks: TZ_RichEditLinks;
    procedure InsertLinkText(const LinkText: string; SelStart: integer = -1);
    procedure SetRichEditMasks;
    procedure RichEditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
  public
    class function This: TRichEditExtended;
    class procedure ApplyRichEdit(ARichEdit: TRichEdit);                              // -1 - inserts to the end of text, otherwise into a position indicated by SelStart 
    class function AddLinkText(AText: string; AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent; SelStart: integer = -1): integer;
    class function AddLinkTextWithDefaultEvent(AText: string; SelStart: integer = -1): integer;
    class procedure AddDefaultLinkTextEvent(AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent);
  end;

implementation

{ TRichEditExtended }
uses StrUtils;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.AddDefaultLinkTextEvent(AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent);
var
  REL: TZ_RichEditLink;
begin
  if (This.FRichEditLinks.Count > 0) and This.FRichEditLinks[0].IsDefaultEvent then
    This.FRichEditLinks[0].OnLinkClickEvent := AOnLinkClickEvent
  else
  begin
    REL := TZ_RichEditLink.Create;
    REL.IsDefaultEvent := true;
    REL.Text := '';
    REL.OnLinkClickEvent := AOnLinkClickEvent;
    This.FRichEditLinks.Insert(0, REL);
    REL := nil;
  end;
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.AddLinkText(AText: string; AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent; SelStart: integer = -1): integer;
var REL: TZ_RichEditLink;
begin
  REL := TZ_RichEditLink.Create;
  REL.IsDefaultEvent := false;
  REL.Text := AText;
  REL.OnLinkClickEvent := AOnLinkClickEvent;
  Result := This.FRichEditLinks.Add(REL);
  This.InsertLinkText(AText, SelStart);
  REL := nil;
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.AddLinkTextWithDefaultEvent(AText: string; SelStart: integer): integer;
begin
  This.AddLinkText(AText, nil, SelStart);
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FRichEdit := nil;
  FRichEditLinks := TZ_RichEditLinks.Create;
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.ApplyRichEdit(ARichEdit: TRichEdit);
begin
  This.FRichEdit := ARichEdit;
  This.FPrevRichEditWndProc := This.FRichEdit.WindowProc;
  This.FRichEdit.WindowProc := This.RichEditWndProc;
  This.FRichEditLinks.Clear;
  This.SetRichEditMasks;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if Assigned(FRichEdit) then
    FRichEdit.WindowProc := FPrevRichEditWndProc;
  FRichEdit := nil;
  FRichEditLinks.Clear;
  FRichEditLinks.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.InsertLinkText(const LinkText: string; SelStart: integer = -1);
var
  Fmt: CHARFORMAT2;
begin
  if SelStart = -1 then
  begin
    SelStart := FRichEdit.Lines.Text.Length - 1;
    FRichEdit.Text := FRichEdit.Text + LinkText;
    dec(SelStart,2 * (FRichEdit.Lines.Text.CountChar(#$D) - 1));
  end
  else
  begin
    FRichEdit.SelStart := SelStart;
    FRichEdit.SelText := LinkText;
  end;
  FRichEdit.SelStart := SelStart;
  FRichEdit.SelLength := Length(LinkText);

  FillChar(Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt), 0);
  Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
  Fmt.dwMask := CFM_LINK;
  Fmt.dwEffects := CFE_LINK;

  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));

  FRichEdit.SelStart := SelStart + Length(LinkText);
  FRichEdit.SelLength := 0;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.RichEditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
type
  PENLINK = ^ENLINK;
var
  tr: TEXTRANGE;
  str: string;
  p: PENLINK;
  i: integer;
begin
  FPrevRichEditWndProc(Message);

  case Message.Msg of
    CN_NOTIFY: begin
     if TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr.code = EN_LINK then
      begin
        P := PENLINK(Message.LParam);
        if p.msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
        begin
          SetLength(str, p.chrg.cpMax - p.chrg.cpMin);
          tr.chrg := p.chrg;
          tr.lpstrText := PChar(str);
          SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, LPARAM(@tr));

          for I := 0 to FRichEditLinks.Count - 1 do
            if str.ToUpper.Equals(FRichEditLinks[I].Text.ToUpper)  then
            begin
              if not Assigned(FRichEditLinks[I].OnLinkClickEvent) then
              begin
                if not FRichEditLinks[0].IsDefaultEvent then
                  raise Exception.Create('No default event is set.')
                else
                  FRichEditLinks[0].OnLinkClickEvent(str)
              end
              else
                FRichEditLinks[I].OnLinkClickEvent(str);
              exit;
            end;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    CM_RECREATEWND: begin
      SetRichEditMasks;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.SetRichEditMasks;
var
  Mask: DWORD;
begin
  Mask := SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, Mask or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, 1, 0);
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.This: TRichEditExtended;
begin
  if not Assigned(TRichEditExtended.FInstance) then
    TRichEditExtended.FInstance := TRichEditExtended.Create;
  Result := TRichEditExtended.FInstance;
end;

{ TRichEditExList }

initialization

finalization
  if Assigned(TRichEditExtended.FInstance) then
    TRichEditExtended.FInstance.Free;

end.
```

To run this code you should create a new Application, add *TRichEdit* on the *Form* and type the following in a *FormCreate* method:

```
  TRichEditExtended.ApplyRichEdit(ed1);
  TRichEditExtended.AddDefaultLinkTextEvent(procedure (const T: String)begin showmessage(T); end);
  TRichEditExtended.AddLinkTextWithDefaultEvent('Link');
  ed1.Text := ed1.Text + '1231232  ';
  TRichEditExtended.AddLinkTextWithDefaultEvent('Link2');
```

Answer (score 1):

`InsertLinkText()` is replacing `FRichEdit.Text` with a completely new `string` when inserting a link with `SelStart=-1`, thus losing all previous text and formatting.

Use `FRichEdit.GetTextLen()` instead of `FRichEdit.Lines.Text.Length` to get the length of the existing text. And regardless of the input `SelStart`, always use the `FRichEdit.SelStart|SelLength|SelText` properties to add the new link into `FRichEdit`, preserving all existing text and formatting.

```
procedure TRichEditExtended.InsertLinkText(const LinkText: string; SelStart: integer = -1);
var
  Fmt: CHARFORMAT2;
  //Range: CHARRANGE;
begin
  if SelStart = -1 then SelStart := FRichEdit.GetTextLen;

  FRichEdit.SelStart := SelStart;
  FRichEdit.SelLength := 0;
  { or:
  Range.cpMin := SelStart;
  Range.cpMax := SelStart;
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@Range));
  }
  FRichEdit.SelText := LinkText;

  FRichEdit.SelStart := SelStart;
  FRichEdit.SelLength := Length(LinkText);
  { or:
  Range.cpMin := SelStart;
  Range.cpMax := SelStart + Length(LinkText);
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@Range));
  }

  FillChar(Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt), 0);
  Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
  Fmt.dwMask := CFM_LINK;
  Fmt.dwEffects := CFE_LINK;
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));

  FRichEdit.SelStart := SelStart + Length(LinkText);
  FRichEdit.SelLength := 0;
  { or:
  Range.cpMin := SelStart + Length(LinkText);
  Range.cpMax := Range.cpMax;
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@Range));
  }
end;
```

Comment: so you are referring to this string `FRichEdit.Text := FRichEdit.Text + LinkText;` which is guilty for totally new text?

Comment: Also you are pointing to use `GetTextLen()`. Does that mean, that all issues with `#$D#$A` and other symbols are met correctly?

Comment: I got another issue: visual effect of Linking is enabled for all parts if I insert a Link inside the text. But when I want do step-by-step string-filling with the mechanism of `SelStart := GetTextLen - 1; SelText := NewLinkText; SelLength := NewLinkText.Length` trying to append a string with a link - only the last one is shown as link.

Comment: And I got the solution: it is necessary to add a `#32` charkey at the end of LinkText: `SelText := Format('%s'#32,[NewLinkText])`. And I have to modify the main code to cover `#$D#$A` issue with getting the *LineNumber* of the `SelStart` position for placing the text and do a calculation of reliable `SelStart` position where to place the text: `SelStart := Max(SelStart - 2 * (Max(LineNo - ord(rioAppendBeforeCRLF in InsertOptions) * ord(FRichEdit.Lines[LineNo].EndsWith(#$D#$A)),0)), 0);`. I guess it would be a headshot if other invisible or non-ANSI symbols met...

Comment: Is it better to modify the topic code or paste another answer?

Comment: @notricky: If you have an answer to your question, post it as another answer.

Comment: I also found out that formatting doesnt disappear if you use `RichEdit.Lines.Add('text');` syntax. I mean a formatting which is set by `SelAttributes`

Comment: @notricky: Internally, `TRichEdit.Lines.Add()` uses the `EM_EXSETSEL` and `EM_REPLACESEL` messages (the same messages used by the `SelStart`/`SelLength` and `SelText` properties, respectively) to insert new text at the end of the RichEdit while preserving existing text and formatting

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @KenWhite I will post my reseach upon the topic with edits about correct text highlighting due to issue of **CRLF** symbols in the text. As I found out **line breaks** are counted as one character for `SelStart` and `GetTextLen`, so you need to find the line where you are going to place a text and count all breaks before it and substract it from the desired SelStart position. For that purpose a function `GetReilableSelStart` is. 
    unit uRichEditExtended;

```
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, RichEdit, WinApi.ShellApi, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Generics.Collections, Vcl.Graphics;

type
  TZ_RichEditClickEvent = reference to procedure(const ALinkText: string; LinkClickAccepted: boolean; var OutData: string);

  TZ_RichEditLink = class
    IsDefaultEvent: boolean;
    Text: string;
    OnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent;
  end;

  TZ_RichEditLinks = TList<TZ_RichEditLink>;

  TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = set of (rioAppendBeforeCRLF);

  TRichEditExtended = class
  protected
    class var FInstance: TRichEditExtended;
    procedure SetRichEditMasks;
    procedure RichEditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
    function GetReilableSelStart(SelStart: integer; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]): integer;
  private
    FLastPressedLinkText: string;
    FLinkClickAccepted: boolean;
    FPrevRichEditWndProc: TWndMethod;
    FRichEdit: TRichEdit;
    FRichEditLinks: TZ_RichEditLinks;    
    function InsertText(const AText: string; const SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]; Font: TFont = nil;
      IsLink: boolean = false): integer;
    procedure InsertLinkText(const LinkText: string; SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]);
    procedure AddText(const AText: string; AddCRLF: boolean; Font: TFont = nil);
    procedure AddFmtText(const AText: string; FontSizeDelta: integer; FontStyle: TFontStyles; FontColor: TColor; AddCRLF: boolean);
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
  public
    class function This: TRichEditExtended;
    class procedure ApplyRichEdit(ARichEdit: TRichEdit);                              
    class procedure AppendText(AText: string);
    class procedure AppendTextLine(AText: string);
    class procedure AppendFmtText(AText: string; FontSizeDelta: integer; FontStyle: TFontStyles; FontColor: TColor);
    class procedure AppendFmtTextLine(AText: string; FontSizeDelta: integer; FontStyle: TFontStyles; FontColor: TColor);
    class function AppendLinkText(AText: string; AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent; SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]): integer;
    class function AppendLinkTextWithDefaultEvent(AText: string; SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]): integer;
    class procedure AddDefaultLinkClickEvent(AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent);
    class function LastLinkText: string;
    class procedure PerformDefaultLinkClickEvent(const LinkText: string; CanOpen: boolean; var FullFilePath: string);
    class procedure SetDefaultLinkClickReaction(ALinkClickAccepted: boolean);
  end;

implementation

{ TRichEditExtended }
uses StrUtils, Math;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.AddDefaultLinkClickEvent(AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent);
var
  REL: TZ_RichEditLink;
begin
  if (This.FRichEditLinks.Count > 0) and This.FRichEditLinks[0].IsDefaultEvent then
    This.FRichEditLinks[0].OnLinkClickEvent := AOnLinkClickEvent
  else
  begin
    REL := TZ_RichEditLink.Create;
    REL.IsDefaultEvent := true;
    REL.Text := '';
    REL.OnLinkClickEvent := AOnLinkClickEvent;
    This.FRichEditLinks.Insert(0, REL);
    REL := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.AddFmtText(const AText: string; FontSizeDelta: integer; FontStyle: TFontStyles; FontColor: TColor; AddCRLF: boolean);
var Font: TFont;
begin
  try
    Font := TFont.Create;
    Font.Size := This.FRichEdit.Font.Size + FontSizeDelta;
    Font.Style := FontStyle;
    Font.Color := FontColor;
    Font.Name := This.FRichEdit.Font.Name;
    This.AddText(AText, AddCRLF, Font);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Font);
  end;
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.AppendLinkText(AText: string; AOnLinkClickEvent: TZ_RichEditClickEvent; SelStart: integer = -1;
  InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]): integer;
var REL: TZ_RichEditLink;
begin
  REL := TZ_RichEditLink.Create;
  REL.IsDefaultEvent := false;
  REL.Text := AText;
  REL.OnLinkClickEvent := AOnLinkClickEvent;
  Result := This.FRichEditLinks.Add(REL);
  This.InsertLinkText(AText, SelStart, InsertOptions);
  REL := nil;
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.AppendLinkTextWithDefaultEvent(AText: string; SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]): integer;
begin
  This.AppendLinkText(AText, nil, SelStart, InsertOptions);
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FRichEdit := nil;
  FRichEditLinks := TZ_RichEditLinks.Create;
  FLinkClickAccepted := false;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.AddText(const AText: string; AddCRLF: boolean; Font: TFont);
begin
  if AddCRLF then
    InsertText(Format('%s'#13#10,[AText]), -1, [rioAppendBeforeCRLF], Font)
  else
    InsertText(AText, -1, [rioAppendBeforeCRLF], Font);
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.AppendFmtText(AText: string; FontSizeDelta: integer; FontStyle: TFontStyles; FontColor: TColor);
begin
  This.AddFmtText(AText, FontSizeDelta, FontStyle, FontColor, false);
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.AppendFmtTextLine(AText: string; FontSizeDelta: integer; FontStyle: TFontStyles; FontColor: TColor);
begin
  This.AddFmtText(AText, FontSizeDelta, FontStyle, FontColor, true);
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.AppendText(AText: string);
begin
  This.AddText(AText, false);
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.AppendTextLine(AText: string);
begin
  This.AddText(AText, true);
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.ApplyRichEdit(ARichEdit: TRichEdit);
begin
  This.FRichEdit := ARichEdit;
  This.FPrevRichEditWndProc := This.FRichEdit.WindowProc;
  This.FRichEdit.WindowProc := This.RichEditWndProc;
  This.FRichEditLinks.Clear;
  This.SetRichEditMasks;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if Assigned(FRichEdit) then
    FRichEdit.WindowProc := FPrevRichEditWndProc;
  FRichEdit := nil;
  FRichEditLinks.Clear;
  FRichEditLinks.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TRichEditExtended.GetReilableSelStart(SelStart: integer; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]): integer;
var
  LineNo, LinesCount: integer;
begin
  LinesCount := FRichEdit.Lines.Count;
  if SelStart = -1 then  
  begin
    Result := Max(FRichEdit.GetTextLen - Max((LinesCount - ord(not String(FRichEdit.Text).EndsWith(#$D#$A))),0), 0);
  end
  else
  begin
    LineNo := FRichEdit.Perform(EM_LINEFROMCHAR, SelStart, 0);
    Result := Max(SelStart - (Max(LineNo - ord(rioAppendBeforeCRLF in InsertOptions) * ord(FRichEdit.Lines[LineNo].EndsWith(#$D#$A)),0)), 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.InsertLinkText(const LinkText: string; SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF]);
var
  Fmt: CHARFORMAT2;
begin
  SelStart := InsertText(LinkText, SelStart, InsertOptions, nil, true);

  FillChar(Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt), 0);
  Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
  Fmt.dwMask := CFM_LINK;
  Fmt.dwEffects := CFE_LINK;

  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));

  FRichEdit.SelStart := FRichEdit.GetTextLen;
  FRichEdit.SelLength := 0;
end;

function TRichEditExtended.InsertText(const AText: string; const SelStart: integer = -1; InsertOptions: TZ_RichEditInsertOptions = [rioAppendBeforeCRLF];
  Font: TFont = nil; IsLink: boolean = false): integer;
var
  Fmt: CHARFORMAT2;
begin
  Result := GetReilableSelStart(SelStart, InsertOptions);
  FRichEdit.SelStart := Result;
  FRichEdit.SelText := Format('%s%s',[AText, DupeString(#32,ord(IsLink))]);
  FRichEdit.SelStart := Result;
  FRichEdit.SelLength := Length(AText);
  FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Color := FRichEdit.DefAttributes.Color;
  FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Name := FRichEdit.DefAttributes.Name;
  FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Size := FRichEdit.DefAttributes.Size;
  FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Style := FRichEdit.DefAttributes.Style;
  if Assigned(Font) then
  begin
    FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Color := Font.Color;
    FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Name := Font.Name;
    FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Size := Font.Size;
    FRichEdit.SelAttributes.Style := Font.Style;
    FRichEdit.SelStart := FRichEdit.GetTextLen;
    FRichEdit.SelLength := 0;
  end;
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.LastLinkText: string;
begin
  Result := This.FLastPressedLinkText;
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.PerformDefaultLinkClickEvent(const LinkText: string; CanOpen: boolean; var FullFilePath: string);
begin
  if (This.FRichEditLinks.Count = 0) or not This.FRichEditLinks[0].IsDefaultEvent then
    raise Exception.Create('A default action should be set.');
  This.FRichEditLinks[0].OnLinkClickEvent(LinkText, CanOpen, FullFilePath);
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.RichEditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
type
  PENLINK = ^ENLINK;
var
  tr: TEXTRANGE;
  p: PENLINK;
  i: integer;
  OutDat: string;

  function GetLinkText: string;
  begin
    SetLength(Result, p.chrg.cpMax - p.chrg.cpMin);
    tr.chrg := p.chrg;
    tr.lpstrText := PChar(Result);
    SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, LPARAM(@tr));
  end;
begin
  FPrevRichEditWndProc(Message);

  case Message.Msg of
    CN_NOTIFY: begin
      if TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr.code = EN_LINK then
      begin
        P := PENLINK(Message.LParam);
        case p.msg of
          WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
          begin
            FLastPressedLinkText := GetLinkText;
            for I := 0 to FRichEditLinks.Count - 1 do
              if FLastPressedLinkText.ToUpper.Equals(FRichEditLinks[I].Text.ToUpper)  then
              begin
                if not Assigned(FRichEditLinks[I].OnLinkClickEvent) then
                begin
                  if not FRichEditLinks[0].IsDefaultEvent then
                    raise Exception.Create('A default action should be set.')
                  else
                    FRichEditLinks[0].OnLinkClickEvent(FLastPressedLinkText, FLinkClickAccepted, OutData)
                end
                else
                  FRichEditLinks[I].OnLinkClickEvent(FLastPressedLinkText, FLinkClickAccepted, OutData);
                exit;
              end;
          end;
          WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
          begin
            FLastPressedLinkText := GetLinkText;
            if Assigned(FRichEdit.PopupMenu) then
            begin
              FRichEdit.PopupMenu.Popup(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y);
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    CM_RECREATEWND: begin
      SetRichEditMasks;
    end;
  end;
end;

class procedure TRichEditExtended.SetDefaultLinkClickReaction(ALinkClickAccepted: boolean);
begin
  This.FLinkClickAccepted := ALinkClickAccepted;
end;

procedure TRichEditExtended.SetRichEditMasks;
var
  Mask: DWORD;
begin
  Mask := SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, Mask or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(FRichEdit.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, 1, 0);
end;

class function TRichEditExtended.This: TRichEditExtended;
begin
  if not Assigned(TRichEditExtended.FInstance) then
    TRichEditExtended.FInstance := TRichEditExtended.Create;
  Result := TRichEditExtended.FInstance;
end;

{ TRichEditExList }

initialization

finalization
  if Assigned(TRichEditExtended.FInstance) then
    TRichEditExtended.FInstance.Free;

end.
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

How to use:

```
TRichEditExtended.ApplyRichEdit(edMessages); 
TRichEditExtended.SetDefaultLinkClickReaction(true); //Link click accepted by default or not
TRichEditExtended.AddDefaultLinkClickEvent(
  procedure (const LinkText: string; LinkClickAccepted: boolean; var OutData: string)
  begin
    if LinkClickAccepted then
      DoSomething;
    DoAnythingTo(OutData); // if you call somewhere after TRichEditExtended.PerformDefaultLinkClickEvent then you get the OutData there
  end
);
```